# How to create a md5 file in c#

Tags: c#, md5, text-files

How to create a md5 in c#? I want to call the txt file and call the md5 in c# to the txt file to hash it.

```
public static string MD5Hash(string text)
{
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text))), “-”, “”);
}
```

Comment: "need it urgently" isn't going to make us help you any faster. Anyways, you already know how to compute the hash, so what's the problem?

Comment: my problem is how to write a md5 in c # and through that call a function to call this md5 file to hash the data in txt file

Answer (score 9):

Stolen straight from from [here](http://sharpertutorials.com/calculate-md5-checksum-file/).

```
protected string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
{
  FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
  MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
  byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
  file.Close();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
  {
    sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @CutexBabies: `"x2"` is the [Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for a two-digit hexadecimal number. For example, `255.ToString("x2")` returns `"ff"`.

Comment: It is the Byte.ToString(string format) method.  "x2" is a format specifier indicating that you want a two-digit zero-padded hexadecimal number.

Comment: if i gt a long txt...will it still remain as x2?  why some of them declare as x

Comment: The x2 is only a format specifier, nothing more, and has nothing to do with how long the file is.  It is telling C# how to display the number.  If the number is < 16, x2 will pad the number with a zero.  For example, 12 is displayed as 0c.  If you just use "x" as the format specifier, 12 will be displayed as just c.  Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: then how and where  am i goin to call this class?

Comment: This is a function you add to your own class, then you can call it using the standard function calling syntax; e.g. string my_hash = GetMD5HashFromFile(@"C:\myfile.pdf");

Comment: Only one remark on this: use `using` for the file stream to ensure correct cleanup. `using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)) { /* code */ }`